# Maximum number of users on Linux

Tags: linux, users

What is the maximum number of users accounts I can have on Linux?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

65.000 for 2.4 kernels, and 4 billion for 2.6 kernels.

Comment: When are they gonna fix that? What if I want to make one account for every person in the world?

Comment: Well, doesn't 64-bit linux support 2^128 users?

Comment: Fun fact: assuming an the average entry in /etc/passwd is 75 bytes, 4 billion users would give you an /etc/passwd that's just a shade under 300GB. :-)

Comment: @shintoist: Because things are made based on what's probable, not what's possible. It's possible that you would want to create a user account in a single Linux system for every person in the world, but it's not probable that you'd actually do that.

Comment: @joeqwert Yes, because I was being serious...

Comment: Do you have any source of these numbers?

Comment: @Graeme.  Haha.  Of course you don't necessarily need to use `passwd` and `nsswitch compat`.

Comment: Don’t you mean 6,5536 (2¹⁶) or 4,294,967,296 (2³²)? (When including root (0) and everything below 1000.) 65000 is a very unnatural number for computers.

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy: Usually, use uses things like LDAP/Kerberos for these situations. SQL-database-backed probably.